# justification of simple idea involving union

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

How would you justify going from

$x\notin$ $A\cup B\ $

$x\notin A$ and $x\notin B$

in a proof, where the same values of x satisfy both statements.

would by definition of U be sufficient or would you have to explain it more?

Comment: You should *be able to* explain it more, but whether you *have to* or not depends on context. (If this is for a homework assignment, it depends on your grader's expectations - how much detail they want.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it depends on the context. If you want to prove it using formal logic, you need more. But in elementary set theory, you wouldn't need further justification, unless the *exercise* is to prove *that*.

Maybe you could write something like this: $A \cup B$ is, by definition, $\{ x : x\in A \lor x\in B\}$. Let $x \not\in A\cup B$ and suppose that $x \in A$. Then $x \in A \cup B$, which is absurd, so $x \in A$. Anagously, $x\not\in B$.